# Karma unit testing webpack:API fatal error handler returned after process out of memory

Tags: angularjs, node.js, webpack, karma-jasmine

I am trying to execute karma unit test cases for my project. When I run the whole test cases which are available in the application, it is failing with the below error. But when I configure to run fewer test cases by executing all the controllers in a folder, it works. How to increase the memory size to execute all the test cases.

Tried searching but couldn't get any working solutions. Any guidance would be helpful.`

```
$ karma start karma.conf.js


#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# API fatal error handler returned after process out of memory
#
/c/Users/AB18082/AppData/Roaming/npm/karma: line 14: 20164 Segmentation fault      node "$basedir/node_modules/karma-cli/bin/karma" "$@"
```

**EDIT 1:**

When i try to increase size

```
$ node --max_old_space_size=10240 node_modules/karma/bin/karma start karma.conf.js

<--- Last few GCs --->

[13860:002BF998]   214803 ms: Scavenge 1021.9 (1358.6) -> 1021.6 (1365.1) MB, 146.9 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure
[13860:002BF998]   217090 ms: Mark-sweep 1026.8 (1365.9) -> 1014.7 (1355.9) MB, 2263.4 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure GC in old space requested
[13860:002BF998]   217243 ms: Scavenge 1022.6 (1359.5) -> 1022.5 (1363.5) MB, 75.4 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure
[13860:002BF998]   217479 ms: Scavenge 1029.7 (1364.1) -> 1029.6 (1366.6) MB, 225.5 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure


<--- JS stacktrace --->
Cannot get stack trace in GC.
FATAL ERROR: NewSpace::Rebalance Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

**EDIT 2:**

After setting those node --max_old_space_size=4096 changes my application itself is not loading now. tried uninstalling the nodejs and cleared

- npm and npm-cache directories from %appdata% directory

Now getting these error when i start the application also.

```
FATAL ERROR: Committing semi space failed. Allocation failed - process out of memory
1: 00BF287E
2: 00FD3013
3: 00FD1B24
4: 00FD16FC
```

EDIT:3

After so much googling able to fix loading the application using the below cmd and still the testing is having the same issue.

```
env NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=2048 node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack
```

Comment: can you please try `node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/karma/bin/karma start`

Comment: same issue after trying the above command

Comment: what is the version of your node? If below V8, can you please update it to v8 and try again?

Comment: my node version is 8.9.3 :(

Comment: i was getting this when I tried to enable coverage on a non ng type angular + TS hybrid.. it was not happy. I would recommend just use ng-test with coverage if you can.. it works much better and faster. I had to disable because my 16gb RAM machine was getting maxed out.. probably my fault somehow.. but I never manged to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue will resolve once you do changes in package.json like below

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start ./test-config/karma.conf.js",
  "test-ci": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start ./test-config/karma.conf.js --single-run",
  "test-coverage": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start ./test-config/karma.conf.js --coverage"
 }
```